# How can shared roster groups in different virtual hosts get presence of each other?

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, ejabberd, rosters

I'm struggling to get the presence of the users of a shared roster group in a different virtual host. My current structure is this:

```
Virtual Host: users
   User: user1@users
   User: user2@users

   Shared Roster group: accessgroup
         Users in it:
             user1@users
             user2@users

Virtual Host: monitor
   User: admin@monitor

   Shared Roster group: watcher
       Users in it: 
             admin@monitor

       Displayed groups:
            accessgroup@users
```

I want `admin@monitor` to get the presence of `user1@users` and `user2@users`, however, when i log into my client (pidgin) as `admin@monitor` they are not displayed as online.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found a solution that worked out for me. According to `mfoss` in [this post at ejabberd forum](https://www.ejabberd.im/node/4496/index.html), there is no way to create a "police office" effect, where one user can see presence of other one, but can't be seen.

To solve my problem, I had to add `watcher@monitor` in `Displayed Groups:` field of `accessgroup`, enabling `admin@monitor` get the presence of `user1@users` and `user2@users`.

```
Virtual Host: users
   User: user1@users
   User: user2@users

   Shared Roster group: accessgroup
         Users in it:
             user1@users
             user2@users

         Displayed groups: 
              watcher@monitor <---ADDED

Virtual Host: monitor
   User: admin@monitor

   Shared Roster group: watcher
       Users in it: 
             admin@monitor

       Displayed groups:
            accessgroup@users
```